# Shippable PHPUnit Testing several classes

Tags: php, phpunit, continuous-integration, shippable-ci

If I use Shippable for CI with PHPUnit, I do not know how to have several test-classes at a time.

If I put all my tests in 1 class, it works fine and I get the reports and the sequence coverage. But if I want to have 2 test-classes, I don´t get the right reports.

**My structure:**

```
- config
- ...
- tests
   - SQLTest.php
   - UserTest.php
```

**My shippable.yml**:

```
language: php

php: 
   - 5.4

before_script: 
   - mkdir -p shippable/testresults
   - mkdir -p shippable/codecoverage
   - mysql -e 'create database if not exists test;'

script:
   - phpunit  --log-junit shippable/testresults/junit.xml --coverage-xml shippable/codecoverage tests
```

**SQLTest.php**:

```
class SQLTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function testRandomStringLength(){
      $test = "string";

      $this -> assertEquals(strlen($test), 6);
   }
}
```

**UserTest.php**:

```
class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function testRandomStringLength(){
      $test = "string";

      $this -> assertEquals(strlen($test), 6);
   }
 }
```

The **log** on Shippable says:

```
 Time: 202 ms, Memory: 7.75Mb

 OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)

 Generating code coverage report in PHPUnit XML format ... done
```

The **build** is **successful**. But when I click the Tests-tab it says `No tests for this build.`. Why is that happening?

Comment: can you post phpunit.xml file?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have access to that project anymore.